# Why do I appear as a Tor exit node despite ExitPolicy reject *:*

Tags: exit-relays

[image: debian-tor]

In the circuit, why does my node (hi-lighted) appear to be an exit node? Or am I reading it wrong?

My exit policy is  `ExitPolicy reject *:*`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know really, but I would think that this is some initialisation/self-testing circuit. It was initiated by 127.0.0.1. When you are the Exit in a normal circuit, you can not tell who the guard and client are.

You can lookup your relay on [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/) and check your flags and exit policy.